# How to store large number of values in list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The other day during Codechef contest I created a list using range function. 
`my_list = list(range(n))`
where `n` was as large as `10**18`. 
It gave NZEC error on Codechef. So to know what could be the problem I tried creating a list with `10**18` elements in it, using 
`my_list = list(range(10**18))`
but it gave Memory error.

So, how can I tackle such scenario?

Comment: What do you need to do with this list? Obviously you can't have it all in memory at once. This is what generators are for.

Comment: Just to search for it and read a variety of blog posts (blog posts can be one dimensional, opinionated etc so don't rely on one or even a few) maybe a book is the single best way, but obviously its not free.

Answer (score 3):

A `MemoryError` indicates that you've run out of memory on your computer. That's not unsurprising given how large of a list you were trying to create.

If an integer took just 4 bytes (as it does in C, Python integers are much larger and more variably sized) `10**18` integers would take something like a million terabytes of RAM.

Why do you expect to be able to create such a monumentally huge list? If you think you need such an object to solve a programming problem, the fact that you're running out of memory is probably an indication that there's a cleverer algorithm to be found, which doesn't require *nearly* as much space.

Comment: there is no possible scenario where that kind of numbers applies?

Comment: @DamianLattenero A million terabytes of RAM? I honestly can't think of an application where that would be useful (at least, not for your average dev posting on StackOverflow).

Comment: @DamianLattenero - Maybe in 20 years we'll have computers capable of working with 1 exabyte of data. I do not believe that even the sophisticated inferometry that was used to image a black hole recently had only 5 petabytes of data. And that was about as big as it gets for computing these days.

Comment: @Omnifarious thanks for the time to answer, I get the point now

Answer (score 1):

You can try with iterators:

```
rn = range(0,10**18)
it = iter(rn) # could be created from other source, used as example
ls = list(range(0,15))

print(rn)
print(ls)
print(it)

> range(0, 1000000000000000000)
> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
> <range_iterator object at 0x7f20cd3866f0>

#I will put some breaks so when you try it, it will stop some day haha

for i in it:
  if(i<20):
    print(i)
  else:
    break

for i in rn:
  if(i<20):
    print(i)
  else:
    break
```

If you look at output, the rn and the it are object that not store in memory all the values, just the info needed to produce them. On the other hand, a list has all the values in memory.

Comment: There's not really any need for an explicit call to `iter`, the `range` object is iterable itself directly.

Comment: @Blckknght totally right, you know, I was editing the answer in the moment you comment, thanks a lot for the observation anyway!!!

Comment: @Blckknght There is... Try `next(range(5))`. It'll say that it's not directly iterable. EDIT: Also, if you mean in a `for` loop like so: `for T in L`, it calls `iter(L)` before it starts the loop.

Comment: @GeeTransit: yeah, that's the difference between being iterable and being an iterator. `next` expects and iterator, but a `for` loop accepts anything iterable (which does include iterators, their `__iter__` method always returns `self`).

Comment: Ah, the difference between iterable and iterator :(((( I thought you meant it was an iterator as you said it is iterable, but like... eh?

Comment: @DamianLattenero Actually this wont suffice my purpose as I had to make changes in the created list as well, using iter this won't be possible.